# How to have code prompt user to enter info rather than hardwiring it?

Tags: c++

I have a code that reorders arrays based on an index. The code works fine when hardwired to add the numbers in through the editor, but how do I switch that to prompt the user to have to enter the numbers for both the array and index through terminal?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reorder(int arr[], int index[], int n)
{
    int temp[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        temp[index[i]] = arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
        index[i] = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4 };
    int arb[] = { 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 4 };
    int index[] = { 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 5 };

    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << "\nSequence array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << index[i] << ' ';
    cout << "\nOriginal array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    printf("\n");

    reorder(arr, index, n);
    reorder(arb, index, n);

    cout << "Reordered array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    printf("\n");

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin >> ..`?

Comment: `std::cin >> variable`...

Comment: Please format your code before you post it here. You can use http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: `int temp[n];` is a variable-length array and not allowed in ISO C++. You could use a std::vector, a global compile-time constant array size or dynamic memory allocation instead.

Comment: *The code works fine* -- [It does?](https://rextester.com/FZZB39782).  It fails to compile, due to the non-C++ syntax you're using.

Comment: What is the intention of the code? What shall happen to those int arrays in reorder?

Answer (score 0):

As Tomas above mentions, use std::vector instead. However, if you really want to use int[] the following should work.

```
int nDigits = 0;
cout << "Enter number of digits:" << endl;
cin >> nDigits;

int* arr;
int* index;
arr  = new int[nDigits];
index = new int[nDigits];

for(int i = 0; i < nDigits; i++){
    cout << "Enter arr element (" << i << "):" << endl;
    cin >> arr[i];
    cout << "Enter index element (" << i << "):" << endl;
    cin >> index[i];
}
```

... Use vectors instead tbh

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on your `reorder` function. As [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397058/how-to-have-code-prompt-user-to-enter-info-rather-than-hardwiring-it#comment103140094_58397058) commented, the code works (if corrected maybe like this):

```
void reorder(int arr[], int index[], int n)
{
    vector<int> temp(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        temp[index[i]] = arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
        index[i] = i;
    }
}
```

see [live demo](https://rextester.com/JTO45254).

Explanation: arrays with variable length are not part of any of the C++ standards. You can use a vector for your purpose that is initialized with `n` default `int` values (i.e. `0`). This is necessary for randomly accessing it. Of course, your solution is somewhat weak/limited because you have to ensure that the values in `index` are in range: `(0 <= v) && (v < NELEMS(arr))`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem of variable-length arrays. The simplest but really bad solution is to use a global compile-time constant for the array size. You can use `std::cin` to read the values from terminal. By the way you shouldn't mix `std::cout` and `std::printf`. Use `std::cout`.

You should add a check of the user input if each entry is unique and in the range [0, n-1].

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr unsigned int n = 6;

void reorder(int arr[], int index[])
{
    int temp[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        temp[index[i]] = arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
        index[i] = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4 };
    int arb[] = { 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 4 };
    int index[n];

    std::cout << "Enter " << n << " values: ";
    for (auto &element : index) {
        std::cin >> element;
    }

    cout << "\nSequence array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << index[i] << ' ';
    cout << "\nOriginal array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    printf("\n");

    reorder(arr, index);
    reorder(arb, index);

    cout << "Reordered array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    printf("\n");

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The best solution is to use std::vector

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void reorder(std::vector<int> arr, std::vector<int> index)
{
    auto n = arr.size();
    std::vector<int> temp(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        temp[index[i]] = arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
        index[i] = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr = { 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4 };
    std::vector<int> arb = { 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 4 };
    auto n = arr.size();
    std::vector<int> index(n);

    std::cout << "Enter " << n << " values: ";
    for (auto &element : index) {
        std::cin >> element;
    }

    cout << "\nSequence array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << index[i] << ' ';
    cout << "\nOriginal array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    printf("\n");

    reorder(arr, index);
    reorder(arb, index);

    cout << "Reordered array is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    printf("\n");

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think introducing a global constant named `n` may be fast, but is a really bad advice.

Comment: @Wolf ok I changed "not best" to "really bad". Also there is an alternative solution.

Comment: your vector solution looks quite good, but in case of providing a reasonable solution, also switch from `printf` to `std::cout`

Comment: @Wolf In the past I usually modernized the code in my answers and got negative comments and downvotes for this. Now I only fix the problems and sometimes I comment how it could be modernized.

Comment: Okay, I see. Maybe we (better you?) should add range checking to the user input stored in `index` before the `reorder` call. At least this should be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To get an input from the command line use [`cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin). You'd also need to use a vector instead of an array to hold a "dynamic array", i.e. an array you don't know the size of at compile time.

Best practice is to put that input into a string, and parse that string, as cin does not handle incorrect input (include string for this).

```
string input;
cin >> input;
```

next you need to split the input - it is easiest if the delimiter is space, for a comma, you'd need a different method (you'd need to include iterator, vector and sstream for this)

```
istringstream iss(input);
vector<string> splitted_input{istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>()};
```

and convert it to numbers (include algorithm for this)

```
vector<int> parsed_input(splitted_input.size());
transform(splitted_input.begin(), splitted_input.end(), parsed_input.begin(), [](auto val){ return stoi(val);});
```

alternatively, you could use stoi directly without the middle step of splitting the string:

```
size_t idx = 0, input_len = input.size();
vector<int> values;
while (idx < input_len) {   
    size_t new_idx;
    values.push_back(stoi(input.substr(idx, input_len - idx), &new_idx));
    idx += new_idx;
    for(; !isdigit(input[idx]) && input[idx] != '-'; ++idx);  // skip to the next number
}
```